# I can not change location of "view" in UIWindowScene while I run iOS app on macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, swift, macos-catalina

I used the code below to fix window size when I run iOS application on macOS Catalina.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      let width: CGFloat = 200
      let height: CGFloat = 400



UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
            
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: width , height: height )
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: width , height: height )
               }
        
}
```

We have base view in iOS as you know the "view".

I can not change location of "view" in windowScene.
I tried;

```
view.frame.origin.x = 10
view.frame.origin.y = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is there might be windows in Scenes. In this case
there is one window in windowScene and root view in iOS becomes
root view in window[0].

So the coordinates of window[0] in scene are coordinates of base view like size.

I did add
window[0].frame.origin.x = 0
window[0].frame.origin.y = 20

20 is to start view under top frame of window.
view size is the same with window[0] unless you change the size of window[0]

```
  UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
        
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: width , height: height )
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: width , height: height )
         
        let window = windowScene.windows
        window[0].frame.origin.x = 0
        window[0].frame.origin.y = 20

}
```